# Use Github Package Registry without authtoken

Tags: github, npm, continuous-integration

In my node project I would like to use both NPM and Github registries. The reason is that I use some packages as `request` or `async`, but I've made my own packages which are stored on Github Packges Registry.

I've tried to add `@USERNAME:registry=https://npm.pkg.github.com/` in .npmrc, but I still need an authtoken. There is the problem: as it's for a continuous integration I don't want to use a token linked to a specific user.

So what could I do ?

Edit: I'm using Circle CI for my workflows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the default `GITHUB_TOKEN` associated with the repository that your workflow runs in.

> If you are using a GitHub Actions workflow, you can use a GITHUB_TOKEN to publish and consume packages in the GitHub Package Registry without needing to store and manage a personal access token.

ref: https://help.github.com/en/github/managing-packages-with-github-package-registry/configuring-npm-for-use-with-github-package-registry#authenticating-to-github-package-registry

If you are not using GitHub Actions and running your build in a different CI tool then I don't think you have any choice but to use a Personal Access Token tied to a user account.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I'm using CircleCI, so I think I have no choice.
Anyway, I'm in transition to Github Actions so maybe I should make it faster.
Thank you.